# Grid layout problems on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My site is ready to go live but there is 1 problem holding me back. Whenever I view my site on a mobile device, for example a iPhone 6 Plus, the 3x1 grid layout only displays 1  columns instead of 3. I can't find out why :(

HTML:

```
<div class="project-showcase">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Latest Work, Projects <br> & ideas</h2>
            <hr>
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="col-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x180">
                    <h3>Title of project</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ispum uion et lism un lium isum ispum uion et lism ispum uion et lism .</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x180">
                    <h3>Title of project</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ispum uion et lism un lium isum ispum uion et lism ispum uion et lism .</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x180">
                    <h3>Title of project</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ispum uion et lism un lium isum ispum uion et lism ispum uion et lism .</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.project-showcase h2 {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 40px; }
.project-showcase hr {
  margin: 8vh 0 8vh 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #222;
  max-width: 5rem; }

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%; }

.col-3 {
  max-width: 33.33%;
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
  margin: 0 10px; }
  .col-3 img {
    width: 100%; }
  .col-3 h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 5px 10px; }
  .col-3 p {
    margin: 0 10px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {
  .grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%; }

  .col-3 {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center; }
    .col-3 h3 {
      margin: 25px; }
    .col-3 p {
      margin: 15px; } }
```

Site url: www.jacksewell.uk

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my code here: http://codepen.io/FluidOfInsanity/pen/RRgvRJ

I changed the hr tag (you will want to mess with it more) to this

```
project-showcase hr {
  margin: 8px 0 16px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #222;
  max-width: 5rem;
}
```

The margin with the original size was messing it up on my phone.

I updated the phone size to this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {
.grid {
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.col-3 {
  max-width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.col-3 h3 {
  margin: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.col-3 p {
  margin: 15px;
}
}
```

Comment: That is not what I'm wanting. I am wanting the .grid class to turn from a row look to a column look.

Comment: I see it on my iPhone now. Is it only on iOS when you see this then?

Comment: I only have IOS devices so I dont know.

Comment: Just updated my answer. You can look at it in codepen on your phone and it works. I haven't worked too much with flex boxes, but this article helped some: https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/